# How can we generate number sequence value if @id value not match with ref element value?

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I am trying to generate the `number` sequence value in the `num` attribute value `e.g(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`. How can we generate number sequence value if @id value not match with ref element value?

**Input XML:**-

```
<root>
    <p><obj id="a1"/><obj id="a2"/><obj id="a3"/><obj id="a4"/><obj id="a5"/></p>
    <ref>a1</ref>
    <ref>a20</ref>
    <ref>a3</ref>
    <ref>a40</ref>
    <ref>a5</ref>
</root>
```

**Trying below XSLT:-**

```
<xsl:template match="root/p">
        <root>
            <xsl:for-each select="obj">
                <xsl:variable name="id" select="@id"/>
                <xsl:if test="ancestor::root//ref = $id">
                    <xsl:variable name="position"><xsl:number level="any" count="obj"/></xsl:variable>
                    <p num="{$position}" value="{$id}"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="ref"/>
```

**Existing output using above templat**e:-

```
<root>
    <p num="1" value="a1"/>
    <p num="3" value="a3"/>
    <p num="5" value="a5"/>
</root>
```

Attribute `num` value should be `1,2,3`.

**Expected Output:**-

```
<root>
    <p num="1" value="a1"/>
    <p num="2" value="a3"/>
    <p num="3" value="a5"/>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a key and ensure that the code only matches/outputs/counts `obj` elements that have a matching `ref`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:key name="ref" match="ref" use="."/>
  
  <xsl:template match="ref | obj[not(key('ref', @id))]"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="obj[key('ref', @id)]">
    <xsl:variable name="pos" as="xs:integer">
      <xsl:number count="obj[key('ref', @id)]"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <p num="{$pos}" id="{@id}"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```